# Is QImage able to open and render pure 16-bit images?

Tags: image, qt, qt4, rgb, qimage

I think the headline already explains what I want to know.
Is there a possible way to open and save images with 16-bit with Qt? And I don't mean the 3*8=24bit or 4*8=32bit, what is quite the same as a pure 8-bit image, I mean pure 16-bit for R, G and B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what Patrice says, there is no 16 bits per component format in `QImage`. The most you can get is `QImage::Format_ARGB32` at 8 bits per component. Even if you used 8 bits indexed mode, the color tables do not support more than 8 bits per component. Moreover, the `QImageIOHandler` class works in terms of `QImage`, so you cannot create a custom image format plug-in to work with 16 bits per color component, unfortunately.

Comment: QImage::Format_RGB16 The image is stored using a 16-bit RGB format (5-6-5).

Comment: If I understood it correctly, Berschi wants 16 bits for each of R, G, and B, 48 bits in total, 64 if alpha is also needed. The format you mention allocates 5 bits for R, 6 for G (which is smart, since our eyes are more sensitive to green) and 5 for B, 16 bits in total.

Comment: so thanks for the answer, 16 bit for each, that's what I want, and unfortunately this is not supported :(

Answer (score 1):

**Qt5.13** is supported

here is the example

```
QImage raw((uchar*)byte.data(), 480, 640, QImage::Format_Grayscale16);
raw.save(QString("%1/depth.raw").arg(fileName));
```

use the flag **QImage::Format_Grayscale16**

Comment: Yes, since Qt5.12. Use QImage::Format_RGBX64, QImage::Format_RGBA64 and QImage::Format_RGBA64_Premultiplied, for color image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libpng (png++) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

QImage::Format not define pure 16 bit but can define 10 bit.
`QImage::Format_A2RGB30_Premultiplied` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html),  can use RGB 10 bits per channel (0...1).
But if use `QImage::setPixel` they still use 8 bit per channel for define pixel from `QColor`.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, there is no format with 16 bits per component supported in Qt for now.

However there is a request opened to implement this, with a patch attached: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45858

Not sure what is the status of this, and if it will get integrated.